# Why do I encounter this error in my code: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

When I see my JavaScript code in the console, I encounter with an error I mentioned above and here is my code:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/portugal');
request.send();

request.addEventListener('load', function () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
});
```

I've expected to get the information about the country from the server in the console. Is it due to using https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/portugal?
I've tried the other country names instead of Portugal but still have this error!

Comment: It is impossible for us to say why _you_ are getting a timeout error for that URL. Maybe you're in Southeast Asia and the server is in Europe and the signal has to travel halfway around the world. Maybe your government is actively slowing down connections to that URL as a form of sanctions. Who knows? All answerers can do is guess and share their experience, which will be worth the same amount.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Given that I cannot even navigate to the URL directly in the browser without getting a connection timeout error, we CAN safely say that the issue is that the site is just taking too long to respond. As to why it's taking so long, you're right, we can't know, but that's not really the issue. What we also know is that it's not the OPs code (except that the listener should be set up before the `.send()` call).

Comment: So, @ScottMarcus we now have two data points; I don't think from two data points we can safely say anything about the state of the service, especially for those it purports to serve (whoever that is). It's taking too long for you and the OP, so we can safely say that you and the OP are not served well by the service. "...but that's not really the issue" and yet, the title of the question is "Why do I encounter this error in my code", so it seems it is the issue.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Given that the code is either correct or it's not and the OP either has an Internet connection or not, the only other cause as far as I can see would be that the server is not responding. And given that this is my experience with the site as well, I feel very comfortable and confident advising the OP of same. Why the server is slow isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to navigate directly to your URL, the page just clocks and eventually times out in the browser, so the resource you are trying to load is just taking too long.

Also you should be setting up the event listener BEFORE calling `.send` so that if the response were to come back very quickly, you'd already have a hander to deal with it.